# Errors Mounting HDD NTFS Partition

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I have been having this error mounting only 1 partition of 3 on my HDD, I looked around and tried ntfsfix which gives me that everything is fine, i tried ntfsck and got the following results:
[ntfsck Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bx5LU.png)

i try to mount the partition through disks to get this:
[Disks Error when mounting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAeUl.png)

And this is what I get when trying to mount the partition through terminal:
[Terminal Error when mounting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idxB4.png)

This happened after an abrupt power outage so hardware failure is not completely out of the question but since other partitions on the same drive work perfectly i highly doubt so. I really just want to recover data from this partition and I know this could be done easily if the filesystem was not an NTFS filesystem, once i recover the data I will definitely format it into another type.

Thanks in Advance to anyone who tries to help!

Comment: Did you try to run volume fix in Windows platform?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu (or Linux for that) will ONLY mount CLEAN filesystems. If the filesystem is dirty you will see a notice about it.

Our `ntfsfix` tool works for some problems but is NOT a 100% replacement for the same tools you have in Windows. Lots of errors from this are shown as "errors" and nothing more.

Please boot into Windows and analyze the errors it shows. It will have a better suggestion on how to approach this. The error is likely more than just a minor damaged filesystem.

Comment: I don't really have a Windows to boot into since I am not running dualboot, guess i will have to get another SSD for that, but is there another way like using a vm or something similar?

Comment: Create a windows emergency usb disk and use it from there? I assume this will be possible too using windows.